# use scikit-tensor for tensor analysis

Tags: python, anaconda, decomposition, scikits, scikit-tensor

I use the below code for parafac decomposition in scikit-tensor. This code is a sample for scikit-tensor.

```
from sktensor import dtensor, cp_als, parafac2, tucker_hooi
import numpy
import sktensor

T=dtensor(numpy.arange(100).reshape(2, 5,10))
print (type(T))

P, F, D, A, fit, itr, exectimes = parafac2.parafac2(T, 3, init=3, ma_iter=5, conv= 4)
```

When I run this code, the output is...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/meghdad/PycharmProjects/tensorInPython/dtensor1.py", line 17, in <module>
    P, F, D, A, fit, itr, exectimes = parafac2.parafac2(T, 3, init=3, ma_iter=5, conv= 4)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scikit_tensor-0.1-py3.5.egg\sktensor\parafac2.py", line 50, in parafac2
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scikit_tensor-0.1-py3.5.egg\sktensor\parafac2.py", line 113, in __init
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'F' referenced before assignment
```

What do I do to resolve this error?

Comment: Where did you install the scikit-tensor package from?  I don't see it in the default Anaconda [packages](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs) and I only see it mentioned on the anaconda cloud [here](https://anaconda.org/search?q=scikit-tensor) and that is the source code.  What version of Python are you using?  Based upon the code in [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikit-tensor) it isn't clear that it supports 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the [source code](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikit-tensor/0.1) for version 0.1.  The only valid values for the "init" keyword are "nvecs" or "random". The default is "nvecs".  If you try either of those you will get rid of your error:

```
P, F, D, A, fit, itr, exectimes = parafac2.parafac2(T, 3, init='nvecs', ma_iter=5, conv= 4)
```

Or

```
P, F, D, A, fit, itr, exectimes = parafac2.parafac2(T, 3, init='random', ma_iter=5, conv= 4)
```

Comment: Thanks, do you have any documentation for use of scikit-tensor? I don't know this parameters (P, F, D, A, fit, itr, exectimes) what's the return?

Comment: Is there any documentation for scikit-tensor?